# OpenVPN and UDP broadcasts

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, udp

How can I get this to work?

Hours of configuring - and no result.
Is that possible at all?

P.S. UDP broadcasts are needed by old games for LAN play.

Comment: Removed "belongs-on-superuser" tag -- this is a networking question with a VPN server, and belongs here.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using TAP devices?

To communicate by broadcast, all participants need to be in the same broadcast domain.

This requires [bridging](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/76-ethernet-bridging.html).

Answer (score 1):

UDP Broadcasts are not forwarded to another interface then the main one. U are fine using UDP as protocol for OpenVPN. TCP would create to much traffic for playing games.

For finding games using openvpn i wrote a tool that clones udp broadcasts from the main interface to the other existing ones.

That makes you find most LAN-Games. Make sure your IP-Range of the VPN is set to some 192.168.xxx.xxx cause some games restrict hosts in LAN from different IPs.

I just released a stable version of the tool we are using. i you still need something to solve you problem check out [link this link](http://www.hanksoft.de/service/46-udpbroadcastforwarder).

greets

Comment: your link is down...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the "client-to-client" option is turned on in the server config.

Also, you probably want to be running in bridged mode, not routed.